# Struct does not conform to RawRepresentable protocol?

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, protocols, rawrepresentable

I have a struct here, which generates errors when Xcode tries to compile it

```
public struct GATToIPPermissions : OptionSet {

    public init(rawValue: UInt)


    public static var read: GATToIPPermissions { get {}}

    public static var write: GATToIPPermissions { get {}}

    public static var event: GATToIPPermissions { get {}}

    public static var all: GATToIPPermissions { get {}}
}
```

The error I get is `Type GATToIPPermissions does not conform to protocol RawRepresentable`. However, I dont get any indication as to why it doesn't conform.

Can any of you spot the problem?

Comment: You need to implement `init(rawValue:)` as well as your getters.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax you're written is what you would use within a `protocol`. If it were in a protocol, it would declare "Conforming types must implement an initializer called `init(rawValue:)`, and have getters for the following properties of type `GATToIPPermissions`: `read`, `write`, `event`, and `all`"

But you're not aiming to write declarations in a `protocol`, you're looking to write implementations in a `struct`, and here is how that would look:

```
public struct GATToIPPermissions : OptionSet {

    public init(rawValue: UInt) {
        //initialize self with `rawValue`
    }


    public static let read = GATToIPPermissions() //set me to the right value
    public static let write = GATToIPPermissions() //set me to the right value
    public static let event = GATToIPPermissions() //set me to the right value
    public static let all = GATToIPPermissions() //set me to the right value
}
```